# Getting error trying to convert varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server

How do I convert `varchar` to `numeric`.  This is the code I use:

```
  SELECT TOP 1000* 
  FROM [StorageDB - BAW].[dbo].[EMAIL_DETAILS_HOC] eh 
  LEFT JOIN [StorageDB - BAW].[dbo].[Customer_Details_201906] cd ON cd.CSTMR_NUM = CAST(eh.[CIS_NUMBER] AS NUMERIC(20,0))
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Comment: Can you check what is the datatype of the  CIS_NUMBER in the Table and if there are any non-numeric characters present in that column

Comment: @Joby - I have checked and they are all numeric

Comment: Can you check `cd.CSTMR_NUM` or `eh.[CIS_NUMBER]` column may have any `NULL`, `blank` or non-numeric values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `TRY_CONVERT` to flush out offending records, assuming your version of SQL Server supports it:

```
SELECT [CIS_NUMBER]
FROM [StorageDB - BAW].[dbo].[EMAIL_DETAILS_HOC]
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(20,0), [CIS_NUMBER]) IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities for getting this error first is you have length issue or second you must have non numeric value in CIS_number field so check it. Then convert it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Code and Test it.

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 * 
 FROM [StorageDB - BAW].[dbo].[EMAIL_DETAILS_HOC] eh 
        LEFT JOIN StorageDB - BAW].[dbo].[Customer_Details_201906] cd 
            on cd.CSTMR_NUM  = cast(eh.[CIS_NUMBER ] as numeric(20,0))
Where (IsNumeric(eh.[CIS_NUMBER ])=1)
```